# How to set up automatic nuget version increments

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my release pipeline for a dotnet core project, I want to increment the assembly version automatically so I don't need to update it manually each time. This is so my Nuget version is increased every time.

At the moment I'm using the `dotnet pack` command and adding the build number at the end using the "*Automated Package Versioning*" set to "*Use Environment Variable: Build.BuildNumber*". Then I set the "*Option > Build Number Format*" to "1.0.$(BuildID)". First, I tried setting the  attribute of the .csproj file to *1.0.$(BuildID)*, but the pipeline did not pick that up.

The problem is that I have to edit my build pipeline every time I want to adjust my major or minor semver version. Yet with the teams, we agreed not to put build pipeline config in source control (yaml files). Is there a way we can put a part of the build pipeline in a yaml file so that we can override parts of the configuration?

For example: I could set the "*Build Number Format*" to "$(Major).$(Minor).$(BuildID)" and then the partial yaml could override the *Major* and *Minor* variables.

Comment: Hi, did you exactly pick the value in $(BuildID) successfully? I'm a bit confused that in your third paragraph that you said the problem is about the Major and Minor variables.

Comment: I can't check in an `azure-pipeline.yml`. The ops department doesn't have access to our repo and wants to keep the pipeline under their control (we and them can access the pipeline online through a browser, but if we put the config in a yaml file, then the ops department can't update the pipeline). But we do want to put some values (like the `Major` and `Minor` variables) in a file in our repo, so we can update them without the ops department having a say in this. Because now the ops department could overwrite our major and minor versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set up automatic nuget version increments

If you want to automatic nuget version increments, you could use the BuildNumber `$(Rev:r)` instead of `$(BuildID)`:

[**Run (build) number**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> `$(Rev:r)`
>
> 2 (The third run on this day will be 3, and so on.)
>
> **Use $(Rev:r) to ensure that every completed build has a unique name.**
>   When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has
>   changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.
>
> If you want to show prefix zeros in the number, you can add additional
>   'r' characters. For example, specify $(Rev:rr) if you want the Rev
>   number to begin with 01, 02, and so on.

So, you could set the Build Number Format to `$(Major).$(Minor)$(Rev:.r)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten that far. :) What I want to do, is have the setup reside in the cloud (not in azure-pipeline.yml), but have the variables (`Major` and `Minor`) to be overridable via a local file (.csproj, azure-pipeline-partial.yml).

Comment: @KenBonny, you could use the the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) with inline powershell scripts in the build pipeline to overwrite the variables.